# Making a Spring Boot Web/MVC server application fail with a human-friendly message if no profile is selected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 2.7 Web/MVC server application with profiles for different environments (DEV/QA/PROD). I have a common `application.properties` with shared configuration and environment specific configuration, for example, JDBC URLs in separate `application-<environment>.properties` on the classpath.

If the application is started without a profile being selected, it fails with a cryptic error message complaining about a `jdbcUrl` property missing and not being able to initialize the context - all this within a huge stack trace. This is self-explanatory for the developer, but not trivial for an operations person.

What would be the Spring way of checking if exactly one profile is selected and displaying a non-stacktrace, human (operator) friendly error message?
I am looking for something similar to what is shown if the server port is already in use.
I would like to avoid hacks and find the Spring-endorsed solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

> it fails with a cryptic error message complaining about a `jdbcUrl` property missing and not being able to initialize the context - all this within a huge stack trace

The more fundamental problem seems to be that you're fighting the built-in Boot facilities that provide assistance to humans out of the box. Instead of using `@Value("${jdbcUrl}")` in your code, you should inject a `javax.sql.DataSource`, and Boot will automatically configure one when `spring.datasource.url` is set. If it's not present, you'll get an error that says "no bean of DataSource is available", and the auto-config report will explain why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a postprocessor for a value . If it is not present, then log your human friendly error error message and quit the application.

e.g

```
@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor bpp(Environment environment) {
    return new BeanPostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

            if(environment.getActiveProfiles()[0].equalsIgnoreCase(environment.getDefaultProfiles()[0])){
                // Your Error message goes here
                System.exit(1);
            }

            return bean;
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: It is a good point that profiles can be queried via the Environment class. I think a component simply shutting down the JVM on error should be avoided though.

Comment: @PeterG.Horvath Completely agree... this is just a template ... based on the need , you can quit the JVM or throw exception or send alert etc.... its all customer need....